# How to install "Cloud Text-To-Speech" with Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I would like to use Cloud Text-To-Speech.

On the [documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-java) I see that I have to install the client library. On that page you see the code for Maven but in my Android Studio, I am using Gradle and I have no idea how to install it with Gradle.

On [MVNRepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-texttospeech/1.2.1) I have noticed that I have to use `compile group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-texttospeech', version: '1.2.1'`. So on on my application (*app* -> *build.gradle*), I have inserted that line to the dependencies. So it looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-texttospeech', version: '1.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

But that gives me the error: *More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'.*

Also, Android Studio tells me "compile is deprecated; replace with implementation". If I replace it, I'll get the error: *Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 151443 > 65536)*

I also tried to use:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
}
```

I cleaned my project and restarted the app but then I get the error: *Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 147675 > 65536)*

This is too annoying! How can I simply install that library??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `compile group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-texttospeech', version: '1.2.1'`, I needed to use `implementation 'com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:4.3.0'`.